# USB to Ethernet Adapter Problems

Tags: drivers, usb, ethernet

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 right after my Ethernet stopped working, thinking it was a Windows 7 bug. Upon installation I realized that my LAN port on motherboard is toast. I just bought a USB to Ethernet adapter (https://www.insigniaproducts.com/pdp/NS-PU98505/6233049) as a temporary solution. Now I don't know how to get it configured to work. Can someone help me?

Comment: There is nothing to configure. It should just work. If it does not, maybe it is the problem with your motherboard.

Comment: It should have native support. I've used many and never had to install any drivers.

Comment: I'll try reboot. It is trying to use "Auto Ethernet", but keeps on telling me the it's "disconnected - you are now offline"

Comment: What do I try now?